# jws application can't load swing-layout

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, java-web-start

I have an old application that use swing-layout  and i have to make it usable via java webstart . It runs fine from netbeans but if I launch it using jws I got this error :

```
exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/layout/GroupLayout$Group
    at Gui.Accueil.jMenuItemConsPHActionPerformed(Accueil.java:2331)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout$Group
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

I have tried to add swing-layout in the jnlp file but I get this error when I run it :

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Impossible de charger la ressource : http://my_url:8080/___JWSappclient/___app/test/lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
```

this the jnlp :

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">

    <information>
        <title>test </title>
           </information>
    <eligible>True</eligible>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>

        <jar href="./lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/> 
    </resources>

</jnlp>
```

Thanks .

**First edit :**

I have removed  and tried with many path but it's almost the same error `com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Impossible de charger la ressource : http://url/___JWSappclient/___app/test/lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar`

I tried to change swing-layout name to sl.jar but it didn't help . 
What I dont understand is why jws try to download the swing-layout.jar from the server ?

Comment: Duplicate of [java-web-start can't find swing-layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118903/java-web-start-cant-find-swing-layout)

Comment: Did you mean to import `javax.swing.GroupLayout`, rather than `org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout`?

Comment: I can't change to standard java 6 code since I have to support java 5.

Comment: What, the spec. has changed since yesterday on your duplicate where you state *"andrew> I have to support java 6 ."*?  Why is it I doubt your sincerity in changing that detail?  Will it be 1.4 tomorrow?

Comment: yeah maybe . Thanks for your great help Andrew .

Answer (score 2):

The element `<eligible>` does not appear in the [*JNLP File Syntax*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html), and your file is malformed as shown. In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11118903/230513) on this topic, you mentioned needing to support Java 6. To support Java 5, specify it in `<resources>`. The JAR containing `org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout` appears correct, but the path is suspicious. Try something like this:

```
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+" />
    <jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Addendum: *I don't understand why JWS tries to download the* `swing-layout.jar` *from the server*.

The JNLP client downloads all JARs from the server via HTTP. Each JAR must be accessible using the relative path specified in the `href` attribute. In particular, the directory containing your application JAR and JNLP file must also have a `lib` directory containing the layout JAR.

```
test/
    application.jnlp
    application.jar
    lib/
        swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
```

Comment: I added the source of swing-layout to the project. I think it's the best solution to make it work . Thanks for your help .

Comment: Good idea; NetBeans will then put the required JARs in `dist` & `dist/lib/` when you do `Clean and Build Project`.